# How to format a date in angular 2 when my date contains T literal using angular 2

Tags: angular, date-format

I am getting date from backend which contains 'T' literal init.

```
'2017-02-20T15:30:44'
```

Can you help me how to format this in angular 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js and the question doesn't specify what format the author wants to get. Just a bit of googling would give the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing related to angular2 with date format you can simply do this using pure javascript like this

```
new Date('2017-02-20T15:30:44')).toLocaleString()
```

<kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/duOjb0jvXi85z3ja80yj?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: It works well. Thank you. How to get a date format in 'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm am/pm'. Can u help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can format in HTML as well as in typescript.

**In .ts file:**

```
let dateString = '1968-11-16T00:00:00' 
let newDate = new Date(dateString);
```

**In HTML:**

```
{{dateString |  date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}
```